# How can I bypass dependency builds while building my clang plugin?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm-clang, clang-plugin

Is it possible to build a clang plugin using an already built version of clang?

I've done all the steps to download and build clang but I don't know how to set up a tool so that the `Makefile` doesn't traverse the entire llvm and clang directories each time that I compile my tool (traversing the `Makefile` seems to take about as long as building my single file plugin).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the CMake build system (which you should be with reset LLVM), then CMake creates special targets to bypass dependency checks.

If you target name is `target`, call:

```
make target/fast
```

And then the Makefile will not check/rebuild all the dependent libraries. There is also a `make install/fast`.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful to know.

Comment: It's quite difficult to find this information online if you don't know about it.